# Perl Expect.pm send control character to subprocess

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a script that uses the `bash` line editor to recall a previously entered command. Here's the simple session I'm trying to automate.

```
$ bash --norc --noprofile
bash4.4$ echo hi
hi
bash4.4$
```

then type '^P^M'

```
bash4.4$ echo hi
hi
```

Here is my first attempt at scripting this using the Expect.pm module off CPAN. The two `sleep 1`s are in there to guard against the possibility of race conditions when invoking the line editor since I'm not sure what perl sees when that happens.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie;
use Expect;

my $timeout = 10;

my $exp = Expect->new();

$exp->spawn('bash --norc --noprofile');

# wait for first prompt
$exp->expect($timeout, '$ ');
# send echo hi
$exp->send("echo hi\n");
# wait for prompt again
$exp->expect($timeout, '$ ');
# use history recall ^P, then send ^M
sleep 1;
$exp->send("\cp\cm");
sleep 1;
print "okay done!\n";
```

It works up until I hit `"\cp\cm"` (I've also tried `"\cP\cM"`). According to the perl documentation, `\cX` introduces an ASCII control character. (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Character-Escapes)

> Control characters \c is used to denote a control character; the
>   character following \c determines the value of the construct. For
>   example the value of \cA is chr(1), and the value of \cb is chr(2),
>   etc. The gory details are in Regexp Quote-Like Operators in perlop. A
>   complete list of what chr(1), etc. means for ASCII and EBCDIC
>   platforms is in OPERATOR DIFFERENCES in perlebcdic.

This is what I actually get when I run the script, which strongly suggests that the control characters are not getting passed to the subprocess properly and possibly aren't passed at all.

```
% perl bash.pl
bash-4.4$ echo hi
hi
bash-4.4$ okay done!
```

What's going on here? How do I pass a control character to a process with Expect.pm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters escapes you are searching are specific to Perl regex. For your purpose, I would suggest you to pass the [`hex value`](http://www.nthelp.com/ascii.htm) for `ctrl-M` and `ctrl-P`.

```
$exp->send("\x10"); # ctrl+P

$exp->send("\x0D"); # ctrl+M
```

Update(tested):

```
$exp->send("\x10"); # ctrl+P
$exp->send("\n"); # send newline
sleep 2;

# wait for prompt
$exp->expect($timeout, '$ ');

$exp->send("\x0D"); # ctrl+M
$exp->send("\n"); # send newline
```

Comment: Ah. Of course. I tried replacing the offending section with `sleep 1; $exp->send("\x10"); sleep 1; $exp->send("\x0D"); sleep 1;`, but it doesn't appear to drive the line editor.

Comment: Well you need to send newlines also after it. I just demonstrated the important part. Check update.

Comment: What did you see when you ran it? I tried replacing my `$exp->send("\cm\cp");` with what you suggested and I can't get `bash` to echo `hi` twice.  ... nevermind you have to actually expect a prompt in between...

Comment: In my case it worked as expected. I was executing `date` command and it get executed twice.

Comment: I forgot to call `$exp->expect('$ ')` in between sending the control characters. I'm still not completely clear why that's necessary but that may be a question for another day.

Comment: `$exp->expect('$ ')` is needed for the prompt. Before running any command  it is good idea to check for prompt.